# How to post an image file to other server in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried post an image to another this server(13003) by `file/toOther` api, but its console.log showed just this

```
------file upload -------
undefined
```

and when I read console.log(req) then i found like this

```
headers: {
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
    host: 'localhost:13003',
    connection: 'close',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
  },
  rawHeaders: [
    'Accept',
    'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent',
    'axios/0.21.1',
    'Host',
    'localhost:13003',
    'Connection',
    'close',
    'Transfer-Encoding',
    'chunked'
  ],
```

I don't know why 13003 server received like this.

When I use postman to post image to 13003 server, then the image file is successfully uploaded
What will be the problem?

**server/routes/file.js**

```
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

let path = require('path');
let uploadDir = 'static'
let uploadForOtherDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../static');
let fs = require('fs');


const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data')


let multer = require('multer');
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) { 
    callback(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) { 
    callback(null, 'logo-' + Date.now() + '.' + file.mimetype.split('/')[1]);
  }
});
let upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post('/', upload.single('logo'), function (req, res) {

  console.log("------file upload -------")
  console.log(req.file)
  res.json(req.file)

});


router.post('/toOther', async function (req, res) {
  let formData = new FormData()
  console.log('/toOther req :: ', req)
  let fileToOther = path.join(uploadForOtherDir, 'logo2.png')
  console.log('fileToOther>>>', fileToOther)
  let infor = fs.existsSync(fileToOther)
  console.log('infor>>', infor) // infor>> true
  formData.append('logo', fs.createReadStream(fileToOther))

  console.log('formData.getHeaders()', formData.getHeaders())
  let headerHere = formData.getHeaders()
  
  try {
    let result = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:13003/file`,
      formData,
      {Headers: headerHere}
    )
    
    res.status(200).json(result.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('file/toOther err', err)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue (see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789)

As a workaround make sure to specify the `content-length` header and the formData `knownLength` explicitly:

```
// ...
formData.append('logo', fs.createReadStream(fileToOther), { knownLength: fs.statSync(fileToOther).size })

const headers = {
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
    "Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync()
};

axios.post(`http://localhost:13003/file`, formData, {headers})
// ...
```